# Function within PHP file claims undefined when loaded from external file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I link to a JS file called global variables and `functions.js`.
I include PHP tags in body of `index.php` and inside tags I define a function called `generateformtoken`.

I call a function inside the global variables and `functions.js` file when a button is pressed.

The function in global variables and `functions.js` loads the data of a file called `login_form.php` using an ajax call when a button is pressed notably this is after the `index.php` page loads so the function `generateformtoken` has loaded.

Within the file `login_form.php` there is some PHP code which calls the function `generateformtoken` and after the php code there is my form html code.

My problem is that the function being called in `login_form.php` claims it is undefined, even though it is being loaded from `index.php`, and after the function has been defined in `index.php`.

Here is my `index.php` file code this is included right after the body tag.

```
<?php
        session_start();
        echo ("ok so this is def loading...");
        function generateFormToken($form) {
            // generate a token from an unique value
            $token = md5(uniqid(microtime(), true));
            // Write the generated token to the session variable to check it against the hidden field when the form is sent
            $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] = $token;
            return $token;
        }
?>
```

Here is my global variables and functions.JS file. This function is called when a button is pressed, and it detects the form doesn't exist yet:

```
function ajaxCall() {
$.ajax({
url: "php/login_form.php",
success: function (data) { $("body").append(data); },
dataType: 'html'
});
}
```

Here is my `login_form.php` file I'm trying to load the content of into `index.php`'s body:

```
<?php
echo("so php is being loaded via ajax...");
// generate a new token for the $_SESSION superglobal and put them in a hidden field
$newToken = generateFormToken('form1');
?>
<div id="loginContainerBackground">
<div id="loginContainer">       
<form action="php/login_form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $newToken; ?>">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password">
<div id="lower">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxId"><label for="checkBoxId">Keep me logged in</label>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</div><!--/ lower-->
<p id="loginFormErrorMessage"></p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

So my question is why my function that initially gets defined is not working when I call it after loading it with an AJAX call? Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, it will be because php functions do not traverse through ajax so you can not have the function on the index page and think that the ajax page then will also include that function. They need to be treated like individual pages. In order to fix the issue, you need to include the function in the `login_form.php` page as well. The easiest way to do it, is to remove it off the `index.php` page, make a new file:

**/functions/generateFormToken.php**

```
<?php
function generateFormToken($form)
{
    // generate a token from an unique value
    $token = md5(uniqid(microtime(), true));
    // Write the generated token to the session variable to check it against the hidden field when the form is sent
    $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] = $token;
    return $token;
}
```

Then remove `session_start();` off the `index.php` and instead create a `config.php` page that you will include in all your top-level php files:

**/config.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('FUNCTIONS',ROOT_DIR.DS.'functions');
```

Last, when you load your two pages, include the config page and include the function page.

> **Note:** *You should include the config page first thing on the page to load. The config can not load after html starts outputting. All your non-html code should go at the top before any content is output.*

**/index.php**

```
<?php
include_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
include_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'generateFormToken.php');
// Do other header code here
// When you are done, start writing html to the browser
?>
```

**/php/login_form.php**

```
<?php
$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
include_once(realpath(__DIR__.$DS.'..').$DS.'config.php');
include_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'generateFormToken.php');
// Do other header code here
// When you are done, start writing html to the browser

$newToken = generateFormToken('form1');
?>
<div id="loginContainerBackground">
    <div id="loginContainer">       
        <form action="php/login_form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $newToken; ?>">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <div id="lower">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxId"><label for="checkBoxId">Keep me logged in</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </div><!--/ lower-->
            <p id="loginFormErrorMessage"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huh? what do you mean?

Comment: excuse the comment above i cant change it as it says comments can only be edited for 5 minutes anyway i was going to say this : the directory structure is like so /index.php, /functions/generateFormToken.php, /php/login_form.php, /php/config.php so would I need to do all relative links from where the files are eg for index.php to include config.php which is in php folder then id need to make the link something similar to this (excuse me if its wrong which i think it is I am only learning php quite recently) : include_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php/config.php')

Comment: oh and i deleted the first comment as it made no sense didnt know the enter button would auto post a comment rather then make a line break

Comment: For pages in a sub-directory, you would use `/../` to go up one level: `include_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');` then after including the config you can use the defines like `FUNCTIONS`, `DS`, and/or `ROOT_DIR`.

Comment: **You need to keep the config in the root with the index page** though. I have updated the login page.

Comment: is there a way to link to the config folder by url such as http://"ip address"/ I have done this on each webpage using a base tag to set the root directory so all links in the pages are relative to the root folder which means I dont need to do "above one" level folder links

Comment: ok ill move config.php to the root directory and also thankyou for your help I appreciate this alot when it set it all up ill confirm the answer ok